# Taking values from list and making columnames out of it

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a list of 45 with the following structure:

```
 $ q1c1       : chr [1:8] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ q1c2       : chr [1:9] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ q1d        : chr [1:9] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ q2a_1      : chr [1:6] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ p2a        : chr [1:39] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ p6         : chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "98" ...
 $....
```

Now I have a dataframe df, where I want to name all the columns by concatenating the names with the values in the lists:

'q1c1_1, q1c1_2, q1c1_3, ... , q2a_1_1, q2a_1_2, ... ,  p6_1, p6_2, p6_3, p6_98, ...'

How can I concatenate the names and values in this way and then change the column names?

I tried to use the paste function and different functions of the dplyr package, but I have no idea to do it.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How many columns fo you have in `df`? What is `ncol(df)` ?

Comment: 'df' has 305 columns, which should exactly match the number of names after the concatenation. 
The biggest problem for me is how to combine the names to get: 'q1c1_1' and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assumed your list is called `list1` whereas dataframe is called `df`.

You can use `Map` to create column names in the following way and then assign it to `names(df)`.

```
cols <- unlist(Map(function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = '_'), list1, names(list1)))
names(df) <- cols
```

You could achieve something similar with `purrr`.

```
library(purrr)
names(df) <- imap(list1, paste, sep = '_') %>% flatten_chr()
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much Ronak!